# programmatically adding uilabel to view controller for xib causes 'No Visible @Interface' error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am only use to storyboarding in xcode but my new boss wants everyone done in xib files, of which I have no experience.

All I have done so far is created a new single view application, and under the 'viewDidLoad'method have added the code..

```
UILabel *scoreLabel = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0.0, 150.0, 43.0) ];

[self addSubview:scoreLabel];
```

and the line

```
 [self addSubview:scoreLabel];
```

throws the error 'No Visible @Interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'addSubView'

What exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self` is a `UIViewController`.  You add subviews to a `UIView`.  All you need is:

```
[self.view addSubview:scoreLabel];
```

Comment: So are .xib files essentially the same thing as storyboard screens?  that fixed it by the way, thanks.

Comment: Yes, xibs and storyboard scenes are the same thing basically

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add a subview to the controller? it should be to the view.

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` is a method of UIViewController, not UIView.
For your code to work, replace:

```
[self addSubview:scoreLabel];
```

with

```
[self.view addSubview:scoreLabel]
```

To add label from the xib, you do not need any of the above code. In your .h file you must declare property with IBOutlet. Then, in your .xib add label and set its referencing outlet to the declared property. I admit, it is not intuitive at first.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.view will be the view of the view controller.
```

so you can add view ie; sub view only to the view. not its controller.
self will be the view controller here